# Vertical center on Safari with translateY

Tags: html, css, safari, vertical-alignment

I'm using the following code to vertical center some elements:

```
.vertical--center{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Also, the parent of this element is always `position: relative`. This works on every browser I tested except Safari. Is there any workaround or webkit to make this work? If not, which way would be better to vertically center things on Safari ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to be using flexbox for this project?

Comment: Not really. I'm using materializeCss framework, and since they don't provide a viable method to vertically center any element, I had to implement one.

Comment: Is flexbox the only alternative to vertically center elements on Safari?

Comment: It's not the only alternative but I found it's a lot easier to just bite the bullet and get flexbox into your code now so it's easier to work with later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);` did the trick =D

Comment: However,as @TimRoberts mentioned,  flexbox is way better.